# How to setup drupal for content relationship?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Using Drupal 6.x I have created two content types: Person and Event.  Event has a custom field called Attendees (of type: Node Reference; unlimited number of values to person).  When viewing a specific person how does one show all their events?

I have created a view (Personal Events) and added a block display.  I enabled the block to show for content type Person.  How should the view be defined?  Or is there a better way?

Modules installed: CCK; Node Relationships; Views

Answer (score 1):

I think one of these modules might be of help to you:

- [Reverse Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference)
- [NodeReferrer](http://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer)

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to my own question.  However, there maybe better answers... I can only hope.

Created content block (Personal Events)

Added this code to the body of the block.  This code passes the node id argument to a view

```
<?php
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2) ) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $args = array($node->nid );
  $view = views_get_view('PersonalEvents');
  print $view->preview('default', $args);
}
?>
```

Added this code to the Pages of the block [by selecting: Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only)]... this drives the block to only appear person content.

```
<?php
//Read URL
$path=$_GET['q'];
//If URL is node page
if ( strpos($path,'node')===0){
//Parse URL to get nid
$links=explode("/",$_GET['q']);
$nid=$links[1];
//Load node
$node=node_load($nid);
//Display block only if node is of certain content type
if($node->type=='person'){
return TRUE;
}
}
return FALSE;
?>
```

Then created view with:

Style: Table

Relationship Content: Attendees (field_attendees); requires this relationship (checked); and Delta set to ALL.

Argument: Node: Nid; Relationship: Attendees; Hide view / Page not found (404) [selected]

Fields... simply selected Node Title and Date (for now)

Filter: Node Type = Event

Anyone have a better way?